# UIDatePicker stopped working Xamarin IOS14

Tags: c#, xamarin, uidatepicker, ios14

Since I have updated to Xcode 12 and VS (2019 8.7.8 build 4) on my mac and updated Xamarin to the latest version (Xamarin.iOS 14.0.0.0), I find I am unable to use UIDatePicker.

[DatePicker](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xYVXC.png)

Looking at the documentation, https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uidatepicker I need to set Style and maybe preferredDatePickerStyle but neither are these are properties I can set in the (Xamarin) code.

Has anyone found a way to get past this to enable the date to be selected?

Comment: It would be a good idea to add all the versions of the used programs. The "Latest" version cannot be mapped to the actual version you're using. And since this likely is a problem with having some incorrect (or not yet updated) version of one of the used apps, the actual version is critical for other to have a look into your problem.

Comment: Updated to include specific versions

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It will work once we set the `preferredDatePickerStyle` and `sizeToFit`, Sample code is given below.

```
_datePicker = new UIDatePicker(new CGRect(0, 30, 0, 0));
_datePicker.AutoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizing.FlexibleRightMargin;
_datePicker.Frame = new CGRect(_datePicker.Frame.Location, new CGSize(300, _datePicker.Frame.Size.Height));
_datePicker.Mode = _datePickerMode;
_datePicker.Date = (NSDate)_defaultDate;
_datePicker.PreferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.Wheels; //Add this in ios14
_datePicker.SizeToFit(); //Add this in ios14
```

Comment: It will, but the two ios14 options were not available in the versions I was using. I am sure they will be!

Comment: How would one leverage this in a custom renderer? The Control object for a DatePicker inside of an iOS renderer is a UITextField rather than a UIDatePicker

Comment: @SomeStudent whichever object you assign the DatePicker within the control object, you should be able to set the above, if not try `<UIDatePickerObject>.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber(1), new NSString("preferredDatePickerStyle"))`

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved it with this:

`_datePicker.SetValueForKey(new NSNumber(1), new NSString("preferredDatePickerStyle"));`

It is now showing the correct selector

[Date Selector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BxfRl.png)

Comment: As you have answered below, instead of using `_datePicker.PreferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.Wheels;` I am setting the value with a key and enum number (1 is for wheel).

Comment: But setting only the `PreferredDatePickerStyle` not worked for me, it started working only after I add `SizeToFit `.

Answer (score 1):

I'm basically putting together all the details of the other answers into the corresponding implementation in `public class CustomDatePickerRenderer : DatePickerRenderer` for Xamarin Forms in iOS (omitted my implementation of `CreateNativeControl`, `OnElementPropertyChanged`, and custom methods for brevity):

```
protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<DatePicker> e)
{
    const int iosVersionMajorForDatePickerStyleFeature = 13;
    const int iosVersionMinorForDatePickerStyleFeature = 4;
    base.OnElementChanged(e);

    if (e.OldElement != null || Element == null)
    {
        return;
    }

    //Switch back to the Wheels style for the datePicker (in iOS 14 the default of Automatic uses the Compact style)
    if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(iosVersionMajorForDatePickerStyleFeature, iosVersionMinorForDatePickerStyleFeature)
        && Control?.InputView is UIDatePicker datePicker && datePicker.PreferredDatePickerStyle != UIDatePickerStyle.Wheels)
    {
        datePicker.PreferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyle.Wheels;
        datePicker.SizeToFit();
    }

    //Do whatever other customization is desired
    //UpdateBorderColor();
    //UpdateBorderWidth();
    //UpdateCornerRadius();
    //UpdatePadding();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I also encountered this interesting problem recently. When we used Xcode 12 to package it, everything was normal, but when switching to Xcode 12 and above for packaging date selection and display, it would appear abnormal.

Because iOS 13.4 UIDatePicker has new features

- @property (nonatomic, readwrite, assign) UIDatePickerStyle preferredDatePickerStyle API_AVAILABLE(ios(13.4)) API_UNAVAILABLE(tvos, watchos);

If you want to keep the original style, you can add this code

```
   _datePick = [[UIDatePicker alloc] init];
   if (@available(iOS 13.4, *)) {
       _datePick.preferredDatePickerStyle = UIDatePickerStyleWheels;
   }
```